# Does splash from a bomb count as a separate source of damage?

Tags: damage, pathfinder-2e

Let's say Bob the Alchemist throws an Alchemist's Fire (1d8 damage, 1 splash damage) at an [Arboreal Regent](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=29) (who has a weakness 10 to fire), and manages to hit!

Would this Arboreal Regent take, in total, 1d8+11 damages (splash being bundled with the rest of damages since it's the same type) or 1d8+21 (splash being counted separately and thus triggering the weakness twice)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, it does not.

From [the Splash trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=704):

> [...] Add splash damage together with the initial damage against the target before applying the target's resistance or weakness. [...]

Splash damage is added to the initial damage and resistances/weaknesses are only applied a single time.